# Get IAM Role information programatically using Scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-iam

I want to receive the role information for a role name. For example getting the exact ARN identifier.

Somehow this code below is not working. Sadly there is no error message in cloudwatch

```scala
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.*;

import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model._
import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.{AmazonIdentityManagementClient, AmazonIdentityManagement, AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder}
// ....

val iamClient = AmazonIdentityManagementClient
    .builder()
    .withRegion("eu-central-1")
    .build()

val roleRequest = new GetRoleRequest();
roleRequest.setRoleName("InfrastructureStack-StandardRoleD-HBLE12VPTWQ")

val result = iamClient.getRole(roleRequest) // <-- Nothing happens after this line
println("wont execute this println statement")
```

Other services like *CognitoIdentityProvider* are working perfectly fine.

I also tried the builder pattern for the GetRoleRequest and IamClient.

Comment: I will test this code using the AWS SDK for Java V2 and post the results. Your imports use both V2 and V1. Recommend that you use V2 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this IAM V2 code working fine. As stated in my comment, setup your dev environment to use [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup.html).

```
package com.example.iam;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.IamClient;


public class GetRole {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <policyArn> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    policyArn - a policy ARN that you can obtain from the AWS Management Console. \n\n" ;

    //    if (args.length != 1) {
    //        System.out.println(USAGE);
    ////        System.exit(1);
    //    }

        String roleName =  "DynamoDBAutoscaleRole" ; //args[0];
        Region region = Region.AWS_GLOBAL;
        IamClient iam = IamClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getRoleInformation(iam, roleName);
        System.out.println("Done");
        iam.close();
    }

    public static void getRoleInformation(IamClient iam, String roleName) {

        try {

            GetRoleRequest roleRequest = GetRoleRequest.builder()
                    .roleName(roleName)
                    .build();

            GetRoleResponse response = iam.getRole(roleRequest) ;
            System.out.println("The ARN of the role is " +response.role().arn());

        } catch (IamException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]